# How to use an If macro to delete columns if check box for that column isn't selected?

Tags: excel, vba

I am working with a spreadsheet with 11 different system sizes on it with each system size representing a column. I will need to use this to be able to compare different system sizes but need to be able to select which system sizes I want at certain times. For example, the system sizes are 1300, 2000, 2000X, 2500, 2500X, 3000, 3000X, 4500, 6000, 7000, and 9000 and I might need to compare 2500, 3000, and 4500. I have put a check box in row 3 in each of these columns to represent each system size and linked that check box to the same cell it is in so for system 1300 the check box is in cell B3 and linked to cell B3. I want to be able to go in and select each check box for each system size I want to then be able to run a macro to keep the columns/system sizes whose check boxes are selected and delete or hide the columns/system sizes whose check boxes are not selected. Below is the code I have for system 1300.

```
Dim System1300 As String
System1300 = Range("B3").Value
If Not System1300 Like "TRUE" Then
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Check Box 1")).Select
Selection.Delete
Columns("B:B").Select
Range("B2").Activate
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
End If
```

However, for some reason, whether I have the check box selected or not it deletes the check box and the column. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hiding seems more maintainable, so that's what I did here:

```
Sub HideUncheckedColumns()
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim ColumnCount As Long
Dim cell As Excel.Range

Set ws = ActiveSheet 'adjust as necessary
ColumnCount = 11 'adjust as necessary
With ws
    For Each cell In .Range(.Cells(3, 1), .Cells(3, ColumnCount))
        cell.EntireColumn.Hidden = cell.Value = False
    Next cell
End With
End Sub
```

EDIT: As requested here's a version that deletes the FALSE (unchecked) columns.

The key logic difference is that you have to loop through the cells backwards, i.e., from right to left. Otherwise the loop indexing will break as columns are deleted:

```
Sub DeleteUncheckedColumns()
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim ColumnCount As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim cell As Excel.Range

Set ws = ActiveSheet    'adjust as necessary
ColumnCount = 11    'adjust as necessary
With ws
    For i = ColumnCount To 1 Step -1
        Set cell = .Cells(3, i)
        If cell.Value = False Then
            cell.EntireColumn.Delete
        End If
    Next i
End With
End Sub
```

You could shorten it up by eliminating the `cell` variable and referring directly to `.Cells(3, i)`. I kept it in partly for comparison to the previous version, but mostly because I think it adds legibility to the code.

Comment: Thanks Doug, I am just running into one problem with the code though. When the code hides the columns, it does not hide the check boxes with them, which leaves behind random unchecked check boxes. Is there anyway to bypass this or to at least delete the unchecked check boxes?

Comment: Select the checkboxes, right-click, choose Format Control>Properties and check "Move and size with cells". You could do this in code, but it's easy enough to select them all.

Comment: Yea, I tried to do that but for some reason it will not allow me to select that option. I was wondering why.

Comment: When you say "that option" which specific one do you mean? Can you select Format Control. Note that you need to be in Design Mode to do so.

Comment: By that option I mean the Move and size with cells. I read up a little bit and think it is because I used Form Controls instead of ActiveX Controls

Comment: That makes sense. I've been assuming ActiveX.

Comment: Well, I am going about it a little different now and would rather delete the columns than hide them. Can you please show me how to alter the code to delete instead of hide. It would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I can do that in an hour or so.

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate it. That would help a ton!